# Pytorch Implementation of Feedforward ANN with Varying Inputs: RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I'm trying to work with a custom Feedforward implementation that takes varying rows of the input and performs some sort of operation on it.

For example, imagine if the function, `f`, just sums the rows and columns of an input Tensor:

```
f = lambda x: torch.sum(x)  # sum across all dimensions, producing a scalar
```

Now, for the input Tensor I have an `(n, m)` matrix and I want to map the function `f` over all the rows **except** the row under consideration. For example, here is the vanilla implementation that works:

```
d = []  # append the values to d
my_tensor = torch.rand(3, 5, requires_grad=True)  # = (n, m)
indices = list(range(n))  # list of indices

for i in range(n):  # loop through the indices
    curr_range = indices[:i] + indices[i+1:]  # fetch all indices except for the current one
    d.append(f(my_tensor[curr_range])  # calculate sum over all elements excluding row i
```

Produces a `(n, 1)` matrix, which is what I want. The problem is Pytorch cannot auto-differentiate over this and I'm getting errors having to do with lack of grad because I have non-primitive Torch operations:

```
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

Comment: If you want gradients with regard to the input, you just have to give your input tensor gradient logging. You can do this with ```my_tensor = torch.rand(3, 5,requires_grad=True)```

Comment: @sebko_iic, my apologies. In my toy example the `f` and input tensor are simplified, but in the real example they are part of a much larger ANN. The input tensor has `requires_grad=True` in the real example, the issue with backprop has to do with how `d` is calculated and how to make it part of the computational graph.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out casting the output to using `x = torch.tensor(d, requires_grad=True)` did the trick in the feedforward.